# How to remove divider in bottom of the AppBarLayout

Tags: android

[image]

I want to remove the divider line like in the picture above. I've tried anything but still no luck. This is what I have tried until now.
styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="MaterialDrawerTheme.Light.DarkToolbar">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="actionBarDivider">@null</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item></style>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:fillViewport="false" />
        <com.jaredrummler.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</layout>
```

Is anyone has the solution for this issue ? Sorry for my bad English and thanks in advance !

Comment: Maybe it is default elevation. try setting elevation to your ActionBar to 0dp programmatically.

Comment: Where did you add your Toolbar which is casting the shadow?

Comment: My toolbar is at Main Activity

Comment: Thats the problem here as they have to be in the same AppBarLayout to cast the correct shadow. Either you try to disable the whole elevation or you put all in one layout.

Answer (score 7):

In the end, I tried to raise my minSdkVersion from 15 to 21 and add the app:elevation="0dp" to the code. It worked perfectly. Thanks guys for the feedbacks !

Answer (score 4):

You have to set elevation="0dp" like: 
`<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>`

**But it seems that this elevation is from your parent activity not of your fragment. So make sure in your activity you are extending toolbar_layout and that activity's toolbar inside of AppBarLayout set app:elevation="0dp** will solve your problem.

Or

Also check your res-> values-> style.xml and style-v21.xml files you set:
`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>`

Or

If you are not using toolbar you have to call setElevation(0) on your action bar. Note that if you're using the support library you must call it to that like so:

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

It's unaffected by the windowContentOverlay style item, so no changes to styles are required

Answer (score 0):

[image]
<sub>(source: [androidhive.info](http://www.androidhive.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/android-tab-layout-with-icon-and-text.png))</sub>

Take a look this google developer resource :

- https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#tabs-types-of-tabs
- http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html
- http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: @TommyWu take a look 3rd link http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Answer (score 0):

See this layout from Chris Banes [cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) sample:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a divider but `Toolbar` elevation. You should set it to the maximum elevation of  `AppBarLayout` and the `Toolbar`

```
int elevationAppBar = ViewCompat.getElevation(mAppBarLayout);
int elevationToolbar = getSupportActionbar().getElevation();
elevationToolbar = Math.max(elevationToolbar, elevationAppBar);
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(elevationToolbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set app:layout_insetEdge="none" and app:elevation="0dp" in AppBarLayout.I hope that it is ok.

```
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    app:layout_insetEdge="none"
        >
....
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```